# How to prevent systemd from stopping critical service

Tags: systemd

I want the node to get rebooted if a critical service is stopped.
In foo.service, I can put "ExecStopPost=shutdown -r", however that
would cause reboot even if foo gets restarted.

foo is a critical service, node cannot function without this service.

What I want is if someone does "systemctl stop foo",  reboot node.

An alternative is to give an error if someone does "systemctl stop foo"
by making foo as a critical service.

Is there any way to accomplish any of the above in systemd ?

Comment: I wouldn't do that as it might cause a bootloop and you might end up ignoring a problem you have in your code, but did you actually try `ExecStopPost`? It's supposed to run only if a service is stopped unexpectedly; not if someone restarted a service.

Comment: If I add ""ExecStopPost=/sbin/shutdown -r" and if I kill the process by "kill <pid>", the node reboots since the ExecStopPost gets executed. I think ExecStopPost gets executed when the service is going down.